# $scope is not defined in script 2

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-ng-change

### Unable to fetch ng-change selected value from the dropdown.

I'm trying to pass the selected value from the dropdown to API call in script 2 as below, but unable to do so.

In the chrome developer tools it was showing error msg as "$scope is not defined" in the script 2( $scope.changedValue = function ()).

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script>
```

```
            var IM_Mod_app = angular.module('IM_ng_app', []);
    
            // script 1: To fetch all flrs from API call. - working as expected. IM_Mod_app.controller("IM_Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors',
                params: { Id: 'US06' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {
               // alert(response.data);         
                $scope.flavours = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                     // alert(response);
                });           
        });
```

// Script : 2 - to fetch the selected value and to pass it to API to get data.

```
               // IM_Mod_app.controller("IM_Ctrl", function ($scope) {
        $scope.changedValue = function () {
            alert("h1111i");
                $scope.selectedvalues = $scope.flv.FLAVOR_ID;
            }.then(function successCallback(response) {
                // success on on change event - call api to get data
                alert("hi");
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors',
                    params: { Id: 'US15' }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    // scuucess on fetching data from api call
                    // alert(response.data);

                    $scope.flavours = response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    // error on fetching data from api call
                    // alert(response);
                });
                $scope.flavours = response.data;
            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                //  error on onchange event
            });
       // });
```

```
    </script>

</head>
    
    <body ng-app="IM_ng_app">
        <div ng-controller="IM_Ctrl">
            <select ng-model="flv"
                    ng-options="flv.FLAVOR_ID for flv in flavours"
                    ng-change="changedValue(flv)">
                <option value="">Select Flavor</option>
            </select>
           <h1>{{flv.FLAVOR_ID}}</h1>
           
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
```

Looks like it was not entering the script 2 itself(Not hitting the alert msg in script 2).

Can any body can help me in the above issue.

Comment: Of course `$scope` isn't defined. The line that injects it is commented out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code.

```
  IM_Mod_app.controller("IM_Ctrl", function ($scope, $http) {
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors',
                    params: { Id: 'US06' }
                }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                   // alert(response.data);         
                    $scope.flavours = response.data;
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                         // alert(response);
                    });  
     $scope.changedValue = function () {
                   // alert("hgjhhg");
                    alert($scope.flv.FLAVOR_ID);
                    // success on on change event - call api to get data
                    $http({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors',
                        params: { Id: 'US15' }
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        alert(response.data);
                        $scope.flavours = response.data;
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                        // alert(response);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Closing parentheses is the issue. Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem over here is you have `flv` value at two places which is seems to be conflicting which is `ng-model="flv"` and `flv` inside `ng-options`.

```
<select ng-model="flv" ng-options="flv.FLAVOR_ID for flv in flavours" ng-change="changedValue(flv)">
    <option value="">Select Flavor</option>
</select>
```

Change value of `flv` to `flavor` in `ng-options` should solve the issue

```
ng-options="flavor.FLAVOR_ID for flavor in flavours"
```

Comment: Thxs for looking into it. As I mentioned script 1 was working as expected and no issue with dropdown and able to select value from dropdown also..

Comment: @Raju not sure, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
IM_Mod_app.controller("IM_Ctrl", function ($scope) { $scope.changedValue = function () { alert("h1111i"); $scope.selectedvalues = $scope.flv.FLAVOR_ID; }.then(function successCallback(response) { // success on on change event - call api to get data alert("hi"); $http({ method: 'GET', url: 'http://localhost:55762/api/ItemMaintenance/GetAllFlavors', params: { Id: 'US15' } }).then(function successCallback(response) { // scuucess on fetching data from api call // alert(response.data); $scope.flavours = response.data; }, function errorCallback(response) { // error on fetching data from api call // alert(response); }); $scope.flavours = response.data; }, function errorCallback(response) { // error on onchange event }); 
});
```